# Something wrong with the hdfs upload based on kerberos

Tags: python, hdfs

I connect to a cluster to upload files via Python. It succeeds with a file of about 36 Mbytes. However, when I upload a folder over 100Gbytes, it failed.

Any suggestions.

Comment: It would be good if you could provide some sample code and details of where you are uploading the files.

Comment: client = KerberosClient(Cluster_url)
for fi in os.listdir(local_path):
        client.upload(hdfs_path,join(local_path,fi),n_thread=5)

However, when it uploaded 345 files, it sucked...

Comment: And what kind of HDFS API does that mysterious `KerberosClient` use? REST _(WebHDFS)_, Java, something more exotic? To begin with, does the URL begin with `https://` or `hdfs://`?

Comment: Honestly, _"it fails"_ is a pretty USELESS statement. Read. the. error. message. then. Google. it. and. possibly. copy. it. in. your. question. (with proper formatting please).

Comment: I use the http://master:50070

Comment: And there is no error message, only the program stucked .

Answer (score 3):

50070 is the default port for WebHDFS on HTTP (no SSL) on the NameNode. So I assume your clumsy Python connector uses WebHDFS, even if you don't understand what it is.

For uploads, the NameNode receives a HTTP `POST` request but will immediately **redirect** (i.e. *HTTP 307* code) to one of its DataNode.

Ideally your HTTP client would try to create an empty file, then catch the redirect, then launch the actual upload on the proper target.

Looks like your clumsy Python connector does not do that. It tries to upload the ENTIRE FILE to the NN (which ignores the data), then discovers it had to redirect, then upload AGAIN the entire file to the correct server.
If you have some kind of proxy or load balancer to pass, your connection may crash on the first upload attempt (I've seen it happen with as little as 400KB).

Solutions: find a proper Python connector for HDFS; or fix the source code of the clumsy connector you currently use, all by yourself.